# Why does the review icon sometimes have an orange color?

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar

Sometimes the review icon has an orange color, and sometimes it's gray. I looked around but did not find an explanation for it. What does this mean?

[image: "review" icon in the top nav bar]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The icon is highlighted to show there are reviews in the queue.

We drop the highlight when someone has clicked on it - for an hour, as otherwise, it would just be highlighted all the time (and would simply get completely ignored).

We are looking at changing the design and the logic that controls the highlight - what is there now is less than ideal.

Comment: Clear answer, but indeed not ideal. On SO I've never seen an empty queue.

Comment: Indeed - that's one of the things we want to fix (well - not emptying it, but making the icon *useful*).

Comment: Maybe you can have shades, going from light green to dark red, indicating the number of waiting reviews...

Comment: @MartinVerjans - we are looking at a traffic light model as one option.

Comment: That's nice... Even better, allow the users to choose which queue(s) is (are) monitored by the traffic lights (or color shades).

Comment: One thing at a time, @MartinVerjans