# Can I disable the red review icon?

Tags: support, review-queues

Related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233): is there any way to disable the annoying notification system?

Comment: Other than a css-plugin?

Comment: through your profile settings, no, but any extension that allows you to block a particular part of the page or add css/js could do it.

Comment: or you could logout

Comment: Sure - go ahead and review as much as possible. If everyone did that, there would be no reviews left and the icon won't turn red.

Comment: that sounds like work

Comment: @Oded I do not know how to move this to chat, but it is undesirable for me to use a system that provides invalid and unappealable critiques of my performance when automated algorithms disagree with my decisions while trying to reduce the workload of administrators such as yourself and ban me from providing further support for a period of time.

Comment: I agree - the review system (and audits in particular) need work. But we do need people to do more reviews. This isn't about decreasing the load on moderators - it is about keeping quality content in the system and trash out of it.

Comment: Actually, it is not *his* workload. The review queues are for keeping the quality of SO as whole. You aren't doing Oded a favor by reviewing, you are doing community work for the community as whole, including yourself.

Comment: @Braiam If infuriating audits influence people to react in such a way as to jeopardise their employment, is the cost worth the benefit to the reviewer?

Comment: Well, if said reviewer can't just go outside of the review queue and repeat the action that made them fail the audit (effectively disqualifying the post from being used in further audits), obviously other reviewers won't do that either.

Comment: This all seems to be stemming from the fact that you've hit a review ban due to failing audits (from what I gather from what you've said in the comments here). While a more constructive approach would be to post a meta question asking for better understanding of why you've failed an audit (which also has the side effect of exposing bad audits so they can be dealt with, and in turn can help you get out of a review ban if you say to a mod "Hey look at all of these bad audits I have reported, can I have the ban revoked" (so long as you haven't failed a bunch of valid audits recently))...

Comment: ...you could also use any of the established methods of bypassing the audit system, such as viewing the posts directly to get a better idea of the context (which is helpful in-and-of-itself as it allows for better reviewing), or even using [a userscript that identifies audits for you](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/ThingChecker.user.js) (though that is not recommended of course).

Comment: The only way we're going to get rid of infuriating audits is if people complain about them. As it is, most of the time when I see people complaining about audits, it just reflects their incorrect knowledge about what types of content are acceptable here. I assume that's because the type of people who complain are the same type of people who don't know what's up, so we need to get people complaining that *do* know what's up. If audits are keeping reputable users from reviewing, then *that's* the problem we need to address, not hide the icon and bury our heads in the garbage.

Comment: I don't see the point of looking for a root cause for a specific user. I hated that notification while I enjoyed reviewing. Now I don't do reviews and I still hate it.

Comment: @CodyGray You mentioned "what types of content are acceptable here." If everyone is given the power to review, it seems reasonable that everyone is also given the power to determine what content types are acceptable here. Audits deny this freedom when people fail them. TinyGiant's [ThingChecker.user.js](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/ThingChecker.user.js) has an interesting comment, "If you get caught using this, you may be review banned." My personal preference would be to review ban myself to make interaction with the system impossible; then it would not be annoying.

Comment: That is a rather unreasonable supposition. The website has standards, documented clearly in the Help Center. The purpose of reviewing is for the community to assist in our upholding of these standards. If you wish not to participate, that is obviously your prerogative, but disagreeing with the official standards is an altogether different position than being tripped up by incorrect or confusing audits. Yes, users can be review banned for cause, but that doesn't make the icon go away. It just prevents you from reviewing.

Comment: @CodyGray Were the standards established by the community? Does the community have the right to change those standards?

Comment: Yes. Established over the years via discussion on Meta, and always subject to change using the same mechanism.

Comment: @TinyGiant Thank you for introducing me to user scripts! I found that putting `$(".js-review-button").hide();` in a user script that applies to Stack Overflow fixes the problem beautifully. In total, about half-dozen items are being hidden on pages now.

Comment: Blue Cow put something on Pastebin called [Improve Stack Overflow](https://pastebin.com/2SXBybEE) that looks promising.

Comment: "Established over years via discussion on Meta" - Well when a bunch of us are instantly closed on Meta, we are silenced.  And Yes I know this is necro conversation, but my question (asked today in 2020) just got closed because it's a duplicate of this one and a bunch of other old questions that got non-answers and are not being listened to.  WTF???

Comment: @Robotic That your question got closed as a duplicate is not "silencing" you. Your complaints were heard; they've just *been heard before*. Furthermore, that people disagree with you that your proposal is something that should be implemented is also not "silencing" you. It's just disagreement. Sometimes that happens. Reviewing is there for a reason.