# Highlight existing close votes for users that can vote to close

Tags: feature-request, design, vote-to-close

**Problem:**

Bad or obvious duplicate questions don't get closed quickly enough. I frequently go to [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room to try to get questions closed quicker, as I feel users viewing the actual post don't act quickly enough, with some preferring to answer for easy upvotes rather than close vote.

This in turn encourages more of these questions to be asked and answered, in some cases badly, reducing the quality of site content.

**Possible Solution:**

Get more people that have the [privilege to close vote (3k+)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to use their votes.

**How?**

Get their attention when someone has registered a close vote.

---

**Proposal:**

After seeing the [introduction of the red review icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red) and reading the below from [shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

> the new indicator draws more people to click the button and to click through to specific queues once the drop-down is displayed.

Could we not do something similar on questions that have a close vote registered against them to draw more attention to this fact?

We currently have the below that doesn't really attract the eye, it's a dull grey colour that looks like an inactive label:

[image]

**Alternatives:**

How about this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

I'm sure if this was tested and stats recorded that it would make a difference, the size of that difference would be interesting.

I specifically chose orange/amber as a warning and not red (danger). A different colour may be more suitable. The idea was that a warning translates to: "wait a second before acting", where acting would be answering a bad or suggested dupe question or not noticing the close vote at all.

Comment: I really like the one with the red free hand circle ...

Comment: @rene lol if only you could get css styling for that... there has to be someway to achieve that. Meta would approve it straight away.

Comment: *users don't seem to act* - not necessarily - maybe they think no action is necessary. Also - highlighting that implies something needs doing which may not be the case and may cause pile on votes.

Comment: Also - the notification for review of "does this need review" is strictly defined with simple criteria - "does this post need closing or no action at all" is completely different imho.

Comment: Wouldnt this encourage a behaviour where users vote to close just because of the existence of other votes?

Comment: @JonClements I've tried to clarify some things with an update to the post rather than put it in comments. With regards to _pile on votes_, only users with 3k+ would be able to act, so I'd hope that on the whole voting would be reflective of the post. I'd also suggest that having people that actually hang around tags close a question would be better than review queues that have robo-reviewers.

Comment: @suraj close votes are there anyway, this would simply give them a little bit of focus. Users will still have the same discretion to ignore the close votes if they feel it isn't warranted. Like I said in my above comment, I'd prefer someone that specialises in specific tags cast a vote over a robo-reviewer with no experience in the tag.

Answer (score 6):

A question having existing close votes is not a clear sign that it *needs* to be closed and just asking for a few more people to cast their vote. It’s equally valid to decide *not* to close it.

When you look at a question, you should decide for yourself whether or not the question should be closed and then cast your vote accordingly. You should explicitly not base your opinion on whether or not there are already other close votes which you just need to “hop on to”.

Further highlighting existing close votes will just make it easier to jump on the bandwagon without actually having to form an own opinion, so that’s probably not a good idea.

Comment: if this was still 2013 I would agree with the bandwagon but wouldn't the balance by now have tipped over to even if everyone jumped on the bandwagon the majority of posts would still remain open? I mean: the CVQ is only 10K because of aging, not because the close voters keep it at that size.

Comment: I agree it's not a sign that it needs to be closed, this is just an indicator to highlight that a close vote exists more prominently. I'll repeat what I've said in above comments: I'd prefer someone that specialises in specific tags cast a vote over a robo-reviewer with no experience in the tag.

Comment: But unless there’s an explicit “This should not be closed” close vote that people specialized in tags can vote to counter existing votes, nothing would change

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a different color would be nice, but it's not as interesting as long as the close state isn't real time: currently have to close yourself / refresh the page to see it.

(I have asked for such a "close vote in time" feature but I was told that since it concerned only 3000k+ users it was luxury)

So when you're looking at a question, and it gets a close vote, orange or not you're not seeing it (unlike up/down votes).

That's a pity, because it would also allow to warn people who are currently writing answers that a close vote for duplicate is in progress. They could check the duplicate instead of keep on writing their answer and decide *not* to post it. That would save everyone's time.