# Disable the red dot on the Review Queue (I'm distracted)

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, top-bar

I always knew review queues existed, and have dabbled with them here and there, but I have since decided my contributions on the site will not be *that*. The new review queue [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) disagrees with me with this big red dot that appears randomly when I'm looking at a page for too long. It's in the notification section that I thought only has things I care about when they're nice and colorful.

Is there a way I can disable the review queue red dot? I'm afraid my [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) skills are lacking and I'd end up removing the review queue entirely.

Comment: If you're not interested in contributing there, why would it matter to you if you removed the icon entirely? Just curious.

Comment: The dot doesn't "appears randomly when I'm looking at a page for too long". It appears on page load based on the number of active review tasks in relation to the thresholds set by the community management team. I would throw together a userscript for you but I haven't seen the red dot in a while, looks like it is doing its job.

Comment: This is one of the greatest improvements SE has been slow-rolling as of late. Please, leave it there.

Comment: @TinyGiant It also takes into account how many clicks/page views on the site you've had since you last clicked the review queue icon.

Comment: @dont-panic how can I remove the icon entirely?

Comment: @aarkerio I don't know. It's not something I've looked into at all. I only commented because I was wondering why the OP would care if it was gone since they don't want to do any review anyway.

Comment: adblocking it is pretty easy. `stackoverflow.com##.top-bar .secondary-nav .-item:nth-child(3)`

Comment: I agree with Spork. The red dot is distracting. I keep thinking I have a notification, when I don't.

Comment: Well, there's always the chance something I care about is implemented on the third nav item and I'd miss it, for one. And I never minded it before it started notifying me of *something*, so deletion seemed harsh.

Comment: I also find this dot very distracting especially its unpredictable quality.  A browser extension to remove the dot it is I suppose

Comment: For site meant to help programmers, the red dot is not gonna help them be productive.

Comment: This adblock filter just removes the indicator of the review button- instead of removing the 3rd item or all red notification icons: `stackoverflow.com###review-button._danger-indicator:after`

Comment: The latest UI update made the red dot even more glowing and obtrusive.

Comment: Agreed @qwr - I used Ad Blocker to block it

Comment: It is pink now (at least in Dark Mode). Due to [the latest changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched)? [An intro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386102/accessibility-update-colors). [A longer intro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The site does not provide any option to disable the red review indicator. Your only option is therefore client-side modifications.

You can disable the red review indicator by inserting the following CSS as a custom stylesheet in your browser:

```css
.top-bar .-secondary .-link._danger-indicator:after {
    display: none;
}
```

or, if you have an Adblock Plus compatible ad blocker (e.g. uBlock Origin), add the following filter:

```
stackoverflow.com##.top-bar .-secondary .-link._danger-indicator:after
```

Compare these two screenshots: the normal site view is on the left, while the right view is after the custom CSS rule or ad block filter is applied:

[image]          [image]

User [@Wenfang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7881859/wenfang) [discovered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402980/4751173) that one of the various subsequent updates to the Stack Overflow design broke the CSS. This has now been fixed, thanks!

Comment: The Inbox has the feature to clear notifications.  Why does the queue not have the same feature?  This feels like a non-answer.

Comment: This is a hack rather than a real option to fix it. This feels like a very user hostile feature.

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance I'm a bit late, but according to answerer (and confirmed) there is no way to remove the dot. A userscript is the only way to do it as of  november 2020.

Comment: Tbh, I think `content: none;` is better than `display: none;` since the former wouldn't be in the DOM at all.

Comment: @Wenfang you're probably right, but I tend to use CSS to manipulate styles only, not content.

Comment: If you are using ad block  on Chrome, the setting is here:
chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/options.html#customize

Comment: If you are using Brave browser you can add css from this answer here: https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018039072-How-do-I-block-additional-page-elements-

Answer (score 21):

[Glorfindel's solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358157) stopped working for me, so I've modified the code as follows:

```css
.top-bar .-secondary .-link._danger-indicator::after {
  content: none;
}
```

Comment: One of the recent design updates broke my script. Thanks for spotting this, I hope you don't mind I've edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 12):

The latest UI update made the red dot even more glowing and obtrusive. Drastic times call for drastic measures:

You can also remove the red dot entirely with EasyList-compatible filter (such as uBlock Origin)

```
stackoverflow.com###review-button > .s-activity-indicator__danger.s-activity-indicator
```

I found this using uBO's [element picker](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Element-picker) feature. The filter may change due to Stack Exchange's UI updates.

Comment: Surely, it would make more sense to just remove the red dot? Changing to `##.js-review-button > .s-activity-indicator__danger` should do that, I believe.

Comment: Well I don't intend on using the review queues any time in the future. Maybe I should get rid of the question mark button because I only ever click it by mistake.

Comment: `##review-button > .s-activity-indicator` is what I'm using in UBO to hide just the red dot

Answer (score 4):

Now that more UX changes have been made to the top bar (which probably break all "current" solutions), reducing the noise becomes even more critical.

A bit like [qwr's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416967), and I like the "Drastic times call for drastic measures!", => I also got a bit "fed up" at the "new" Inbox Indicators (March/April 2022) (Several Links: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377568) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416927/3799241)), especially the huge and ugly 'Review Queues' one that never disappears and is always calling for "attention"... :grrrrrr...!:

=> Currently on FF98 (only using this Browser (Version) because SO doesn't work otherwise in any of my "Prod" Browsers (Specialist in Web-Automation)), I went to (re-)install the '[uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)' Add-on (on top of `Ghostery` I already had, ... which couldn't do the job, and even did "its best" to (try to) prevent me from installing 'uBlock' :shocking: , but OK, a simple "Element Pick-up" in 'uBlock' does the job...! :happy:

And the Filter I used is:

```scala
stackoverflow.com###review-button > .s-activity-indicator__danger.s-activity-indicator
```

Filter adding/importing can be "a bit tricky", for 'uBlock', can be "reached" from the 'uBlock (Origin)' Icon => 'Settings' => 'My filters'.

---

EDIT [2022-04-05]:
And yet another UX Change, the Top Bar (containing all Activity Indicators) is now Sticky (again). (Links: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411043/3799241) + [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973))

=> If want to make the Top Bar Unsticky (back), => can also add the following Line to the 'uBlock (Origine)' Filters:

```scala
superuser.com,serverfault.com,stackoverflow.com,askubuntu.com,mathoverflow.net,stackexchange.com##.js-top-bar:style(position: absolute!important;)
```

(Taken from [this Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411125/3799241) by User @[douira](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5767124/douira) in the 1st Link...)

Comment: `stackoverflow.com###review-button > .s-activity-indicator` should be enough

Comment: @tdy, yep sure, but maybe some "later" Indicator might be implemented that I might not want to block, can always make a Filter more generic "later" if new HTML Elements "appear", that I/we "also" want to block...

Comment: I was being melodramatic. But I haven't used the review queues or the help center buttons in a while so I might as well just remove them and save some clutter.

Comment: @qwr, "melodramatic", boah..., I just had the same Feeling like you, I even had to (re-)install some Ad-Blocking Add-on, and even (just) wrote a [Review](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/reviews/1824535/#show-more), ah-ah...!