# Why is sticky-navigation back?

Tags: support, top-bar, user-experience

I noticed since last night (PST) [that the much-maligned fixed/sticky header from 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar) has come back.

[image]

[There *was* a setting to control it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation), but unfortunately my SO settings page doesn't have the checkbox to enable/disable the sticky header either:

[image]

Comment: *"There was a setting to control it, but unfortunately my SO settings page doesn't have the checkbox to enable/disable the sticky header either"* - Yeah, SE Inc. decided it would be a good idea to get rid of it: [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368973/we-ve-removed-the-option-to-disable-the-fixed-top-bar), so unfortunately, for the time being, you're SOOL

Comment: That linked page is an _infuriating read_: if they had a pin/unpin button directly on the header then they'd have very, very different stats.

Comment: "We determined no one clicked on the option was on display in a dark cellar without stairs in a locked filing cabinet"

Comment: @Dai I think the post score agrees with you.

Comment: @Dai - It was a infuriating read the two changes ago, at this point, that read is beyond infuriating since at this point it’s falling on deaf ears (feedback on changes like that are completely and intentional being ignored).

Comment: At this point it is probably smarter to do what you can to not be infuriated rather than hope that the source will change their ways...

Comment: @Gimby or... We can actually channel the fury to ensure the "SE makes unilateral changes that removes features used by community members" cry is heard even in the most distant parts of the net :)

Comment: ... I really wonder why SE keeps posting these informational posts as the one on MSE. It's not like they are asking for feedback or anything, it would be best for everyone if everyone stopped pretending.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I would assume it's easier to post an unpopular post and let it fade away due to downvotes than wait for someone to make a post that will be heavily upvoted and thus be far more visible, though, that would also be assuming they're putting way more thought into it than I think they are, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 10):

As you obviously already have [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) installed, you can add a custom CSS injection rule like this to have the top menu bar unstuck:

```lisp
superuser.com,serverfault.com,stackoverflow.com,askubuntu.com,mathoverflow.net,stackexchange.com##.js-top-bar:style(position: absolute!important;)
```

This includes a bunch of domains I found that have SE sites. The `stackexchange.com` part will also apply this to all subdomains. The `!important` part is important because the rule doesn't have strong enough specificity to override the already present rules otherwise.

You can add this rule to your list of custom blocking rules in the "My filters" tab of the uBlock Origin settings page.

Comment: idk why the code block was removed, it's back now though.

Comment: As of April 2022, the sticky bar is back and this variation fixed it for me: `superuser.com,serverfault.com,stackoverflow.com,askubuntu.com,mathoverflow.net,stackexchange.com##.js-top-bar:style(position: absolute!important;)`

Comment: @MatthiasBraun thanks, I've updated it.

Comment: Yep, very good, works fine with uBO on FF98 (per 2022-04-05), and I use it in combination with `stackoverflow.com###review-button > .s-activity-indicator__danger.s-activity-indicator` to also remove the annoying Red Dot from the Review Queues in that same Top Bar...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser extension (add-on) called **"Hide Fixed Elements"** to turn it on and off.

- Hide Fixed Elements for **Google Chrome**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-fixed-elements/ijofpfmngamdbijanehbibnlphlcdmle
- Hide Fixed Elements for **Firefox**: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-fixed-elements

Or use a **custom userscript** or **custom CSS** from here:

- [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368973/we-ve-removed-the-option-to-disable-the-fixed-top-bar)

Comment: Isn't that a big of an overkill for `.top-bar.js-top-bar{position: absolute;}`?

Comment: Such a CSS injection could also be implemented by adding a uBlock Origin CSS injecting filter rule if you already have uBO installed.

Comment: wow, I had no idea uBO could even do that, thanks @douira. I shall accept no commentary as to what that implies about my ability to read documentation :D

Comment: to your credit, the uBO documentation is very long and I also find it hard to search things in it by googling