# New reputation activity indicator looks unfinished

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, top-bar

A new activity indicator design has been available on Stack Overflow for a few minutes now. I know people have different tastes, but this activity indicator doesn’t look good. It looks a bit unfinished. The old one looked quite good.

I hope it will still be adjusted. For example, the overlapping was solved better before. See screenshots. Or the padding within the activity indicator. It looks like you can add `padding-top: 1px`. But as I said, it’s my personal opinion.

[image: Screenshot of old activity indicators.]
[image: Screenshot of new activity indicators.]

I would be interested to know if you also see it that way. Because, to be honest, I find the old design of the activity indicator a bit clearer and more concise.

I think that Stack Overflow should at least think about improving the design of the new activity indicator. It is definitely smaller and therefore less readable. Suggestion would be to increase the text or increase the padding. The slight light shadow around the badge looks fancy but it makes it more difficult to read. Especially on monitors with a high resolution, you have to look closely. Maybe it would help to remove the light shadow. So that you have more contrast to the writing.

Comment: MSE dupe: [Idea behind new top header icon color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377568/294055)

Comment: You'll need to add some detail to this question: What looks bad? Why? How would it be improved? _"This doesn't look good"_ isn't actionable feedback.

Comment: Actually, there is already an offical name for it: [activity indicator](//stackoverflow.design/product/components/activity-indicator).

Comment: As a side comment. The review queue indicator is so annoyingly drawing attention (even much more than before) that I had to block it right away. Quite fittingly the element's class is called "danger".

Comment: Darn kids still won't stay off my lawn.

Comment: As with every change the question is "how do I take it back?"

Comment: @Trilarion I felt the same way and found the meta question about it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358150/3163618

Comment: The review red dot with the aura is way too intrusive now.

Comment: I will never understand the urge to change what was perfectly working

Comment: @Steve You never go shopping and buy some new outfit or move furniture around in your apartment because you're bored with what is existing?

Comment: I'd just like to voice my opinion that after getting used to it, I like the changes.

Comment: `Hurray - the activity indicator looks finished! Thank you!` Many thanks to the Team for reversing the design changes to the activity indicator. It looks good again and most importantly it's readable and not obtrusive.

I didn't think that the criticism would be accepted. I am really surprised. Thanks

Answer (score 72):

Hint to the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange designers:

A solid fraction of your user base is already old, and we will (hopefully) get older over the next years.

Leading to: eyesight might be more and more of an issue for some of your users. So reducing the contrast area isn't a good choice, at least for some of your users.

The old notification hit a sweet spot for me, and I **immediately** noticed the change (dark theme) and disliked it.

Comment: I find the number barely legible even on MSE and here on MSO. So, I don't think it's even theme related. The **1** in the notifications looks like a straight line. It could be a **7** (in some fonts), it's really hard to make out. I could move closer to my monitor but I don't think I should.

Comment: "your user base is already old ... The old notification hit a sweet spot for me, and I immediately noticed" maybe is time to change to OldCat, hmm?

Comment: I have to use SO/SE on at least 133% magnification. 100% is unusable

Comment: @Braiam As you can see, I am already pretty grey. Albeit some more decades before turning into a real (grauer Panther) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graue_Panther_(Partei).

Comment: @qwr Ironically, using the site with any magnification is considered an unsupported configuration by the developers, and they are unwilling to fix any bugs that result from such magnification levels.

Comment: The always-on indicator on the review queues icon is a visual hindrance for me, and distracts me every single time I open any SO page. Not sure if this is indeed a desired effect, but it takes away from my SO experience. (I personally have used ublock origin's handy picker to get rid of it, but of course that's not ideal)

Comment: I am already in the "ignore that part of the screen" phase which is probably not what they hoped for.

Answer (score 60):

Not that Stack Overflow is going to accept this feedback, but please revert this.  To GhostCat's earlier point, the older notification was *enough*.

Comment: I wish SO devs/POs would **ask the community** for their opinion **before** doing any work much less rolling out a change that the community doesn't like, instead of cooking up an idea in the vacuum of the ivory tower and launching it from orbit.

Comment: @Bohemian as sympathetic as I am to your argument, design-by-committee does not have a great reputation...

Comment: @JaredSmith I would liken my sentiment more to crowd sourcing idea validation rather than design by committee. If the great majority of a very large community thinks an idea sucks, it probably does suck.

Comment: @Bohemian:  I don't think I can hope for that, but I *would* hope that the devs/POs would accept that something is unpopular and commit to reverting it or changing it.  [There is no shame in admitting you're wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385331/1079354) and it makes the effort collaborative instead of competitive.  To be blunt - [they're not taking that approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375489/175248), so it's whatever at this point.  It's no surprise then why they would have anxiety in talking about new features with us given that we're always kept at arms' length.

Answer (score 24):

Since answers here seem to be getting used as comments for additional discussion, I'll add my own as an answer:

This seems to be probably part of the same change.  It seems to be more noticeable than before, but it's *distracting* and should probably be reverted:

[image]

Dear Stack Overflow: One of the very important keys to the success of Stack Exchange sites is a *clean, non-distracting, non-spammy UI*.

Comment: I'm mostly ambivalent to the new rep icons (I probably *slightly* preferred the old way, but it doesn't really bother me). But the giant, noticeable red circle that's *always there* around the review queues really needs to go. That's way too attention-grabbing for something that's literally always there.

Comment: Yeah, this one really bugged me too. I opened all of the review queues and it went away. (I hadn't opened any of them in quite a while before that.)

Comment: Never mind, it's back. That didn't last long. I don't really understand what determines whether it shows up or not. I don't think I'm going to do a bunch of reviews to try to get it go away again.

Answer (score 3):

I added an answer addressing this to [the sibling post over at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377749/395497).

Short version - We updated the indicators to remove the transparent shadow because it made the indicator count as well as the icon below a bit hard to read/visually absorb

Comment: Thank you for adapting the "fuzzy outline"! I really like it overall! :-)

Comment: ...but you kept the roundedness of the indicators and kept the text tiny in it for...reasons?

Comment: to repurpose an existing module rather than a single use one, that way when someone inevitably breaks it they all break equally

Comment: Could we repurpose that module in a way that doesn't crowd the numbers? The round implementation removes the padding between the numbers and the edges of the indicator -> making it look cheap and half done. The square frame retained more visual weight and appeal