# How do I disable the Moderator Election notifications?

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications, moderator-election

The moderator elections are running currently, meaning that I and every other user get multiple notifications bugging us to participate:

[image]

I honestly do not care for the moderator elections, but I find these notifications to be a distraction from my work.
Is it possible to disable these notifications?

Comment: Once you've read it, it goes away, no? Mine did. Are you saying it keeps being marked as "unread"?

Comment: No it is not broken, I don't want to see it ever.

Comment: you can't disable them. But it's just max three notifications (nomination (requires that you can nominate), primaries (requires that primaries takes place; hasn't happened in years), and the election (requires that you can vote)) that all go away when you read them. Just... ignore them?

Comment: That's what I have been doing for 9 years. Can't hurt to ask.

Comment: I must be honest, if you find 3 notification a ~year (for a total of ~27 in the 9 years you've been a member) a distraction from your work, then the 3 notifications you've had from this question alone in the last 30 minutes must be significantly impactful to your work.

Comment: I would think the Red Dot for the Review Queues is much more [disturbing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416973/3799241)... (Link to disable it, and to make the Nav/Notif Bar unsticky...)

Comment: I'm surprised nobody found the dupe earlier.

Comment: And spending time writing this question and interacting with it, is not *a distraction from your work*? or maybe you took a day off to write this question?

Comment: It seems like I may have pissed off some people with that remark. I would like to apologize for that. The duplicate people found has some good arguments, for example I did not know that every community I am a part of has its own elections, which all generate notifications, which is probably why this is bugging me more than it should. However I do believe that this is a valid question to make. While my stance on this may differ from yours, I still believe that I should be able to ask this without being shunned.

Comment: "Can't hurt to ask." - so many question bans were caused by this sequence of words.

Comment: That does not make the question less valid. I could probably have searched more for duplicates beforehand, but searching for these things isn't always easy.

Answer (score 14):

The right to vote is something that's not to be taken lightly. Elections everywhere are important, even on a site that, let's face it, for most of us is merely a pastime.

So if there's an election, which happens like once a year at most, the site owners/developers wanted to notify all users about that, because it's an important happening.

Creating an opt-out for such notifications costs effort, and developer time can be better spent on many more important features, so I'm afraid your request won't be fulfilled in the foreseeable future.