# Why am I constantly being asked to review suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently reviewed 40 suggested edits, and now I'm being asked to do the same again.

Why am I being picked on to do this?

[image]

Comment: Because with reaching 2000 reputation points you are awarded the [Edit Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) priviledge, which also includes the access to the pending edits queue

Comment: Note that specially for the suggested edit queue we can use more reviewers.

Comment: If you feel you are being _picked on_ that might be a suitable topic to bring up on [meta]; but the main gripe many of us have with the blip on the icon next to your recent reputation changes on the site top bar is mainly that it's too _unintrusive._ Most users pay absolutely no attention to it, and it was made even more obscure than it once was.

Comment: "Constantly Being Asked to Approve/Reject Questions" "and now being asked to do the same again." How so? There should only be a rather unobtrusive review icon in the top bar. There have already been multiple requests to *make* it obtrusive because it is so easy to not just ignore but outright not notice at all.

Comment: ok, my apologies for the complaint. I understand. I won't pay any attention to the icon. Thank you

Comment: Adblock is fairly effective at removing the dot, along with the icon

Comment: Well, Reviewers are needed for the Site, especially for Users with <2k-Rep, but if you _really_ find the Red Dot too annoying, I had posted a way to disable it in [this Thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416973/3799241). The same Thread also contains 3 more Solutions by other Users... // In the same Answer of mine, I also posted a way to make the Top Bar "unsticky", which will make the Red Dot already a bit less obtrusive as it won't remain constantly visible as you scroll down on SO/Meta/SE Pages...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Congratulations!

You've been selected to become the next awesome Suggested Edit Reviewer! Your first 40 reviews are appreciated and that surely shouldn't be your last reviews!  We guarantee you fresh reviews every day! And after your first [Custodian badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=15520615) there are more to grab! Go for [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) or even [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward)!

In all seriousness: This site needs more reviewers to deal with the queues. If you can't do 40 each and every day, picking up a few now and then is appreciated as well. Don't get put-off by red-dots and feeling pressured. We can build this better place on the internet, together.

See also [Reviewer overboard! Or a request to improve the onboarding guidance for new reviewers in the suggested edits queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349/reviewer-overboard-or-a-request-to-improve-the-onboarding-guidance-for-new-revi) and if you need company during reviewing join [the SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: Ja. The edit queue is only something like 500 edits deep, and there's a lot more crap out there that needs editing than that. I weep for all those who tried to contribute to clean up, but the queue was full.

Comment: I don't quite understand why I should be doing boring busy-work for free, for the benefit of a private company. When I could be doing boring busy-work for free, for the benefit of a non-profit, open source community. If the private company wants me to do boring busy-work, I'm available for a reasonable salary.

Comment: @Lundin Because you are using this site and its infrastructure for free, aren't you?

Comment: @derpirscher Lundin's more on the production side than the consumption side by about 2 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Lundin: Re *"doing boring busy-work for free, for the benefit of a non-profit, open source community"* You know that isn't possible. It immediately results in some server error (for several years now) - "`500 server error`". Doing boring busy-work for free, for the benefit of a private company at least doesn't result in a server error.

Comment: @derpirscher Ignoring contribution of site content, I've done 5328 reviews and got all the moderation gold badges in 13 years. You've done 105 in 9 years. It's great to hear that you'll be stepping up now and do your part.

Comment: @PeterMortensen So volunteer in helping out with the servers and site development?