# Review banned visual glitch

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-suspension

I'm currently review banned, yet when I open the SO page every day or so, there's always a red dot which should mean that [there are queues that I should review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355234/8560567), but I obviously can't since I'm banned. If I refresh the page, the red dot disappears, but after a day or so the same thing happens again.

[image]

It's also annoying that I can't really tell if I'm still banned, or if there are actually no available review queues for me to review.

Comment: Is it related to *[Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)*?